# Parsing the JSON returned by a Django REST Framework API call

Tags: javascript, json, django

In my Javascript app I make an API call to my Django server's `/rest-auth/registration code`. If the registration attempt fails the API call returns the following JOSN which I am having problems parsing:

```
{
    "_body":"{\"email\":[\"Enter a valid email address.\"],\"username\":[\"A user with that username already exists.\"]}",
    "status":400,
    "ok":false,
    "statusText":"Bad Request",
    "headers":{
        "Server":[
            "Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3"
        ],
        "Transfer-Encoding":[
            "Identity"
        ],
        "Content-Type":[
            "application/json"
        ],
        "Date":[
            "Thu",
            " 20 Oct 2016 13:10:04 GMT"
        ],
        "Connection":[
            "close"
        ],
        "X-Frame-Options":[
            "SAMEORIGIN"
        ],
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":[
            "*"
        ],
        "Allow":[
            "POST",
            " OPTIONS"
        ]
    },
    "type":2,
    "url":"http://www.worldimagearchive.com/rest-auth/registration/"
}
```

I can see how to pull out the 'status' and 'ok' values (using `err.status` & `err.ok`) but can't work out how to parse the "_body" section which may or may not contain errors for email, username, etc.

What do I need to do to get the value of the `\"email\"` section (and test if that section exists by the way) ?

Comment: A simple `_body.email` doesn't work?

Comment: `JSON.parse(data["_body"])["email"]`

Comment: JSON.parse(data["_body"])["email"] did it for me. Thanks Mamdou

Comment: I am getting an exception when trying to do that in Browser.

Comment: I use data._body not data["_body"] and that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well its a JSON inside a JSON. I tried numerous things and nothing worked, so here is an unconventional method to grab the email.

```
err=err.replace('"{','{').replace('}"','}'). replace(/\\/gi, '')
JSON.parse(input)._body.email;//"Enter a valid email address."
```